# Do you know vs. Did you know

Tags: difference

Do you perceive any difference between "Do you know" and "Did you know" in the following? I know the second one seems more common.

> Do you know, when I went out this morning that man was still there.

> Did you know, when I went out this morning that man was still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find *do you know* natural in this context (announcing a surprising fact which your hearer almost certainly *doesn't* know).

We use *did you know* when it's an item of news or a fact about the world that they may already have heard.

> Did you know that Jane and John got married last week?
>
> Did you know that the basking shark is the second largest fish in the sea?